# WFS - from PostGIS to Shapefile with GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, openlayers-2, wfs, getfeature

From server side, I'm using GeoServer and from client side I'm using OpenLayers to allow the users see the layers (PostGIS) on the map.
The new requirement is that the users may download layers in shapefile format.

What is the best way to do this?

I would prefer add the option to download them in the same map view.

Comment: set the format to SHAPE-ZIP

Comment: @iant sorry, I am very newbie. Where and how to set the format to SHAPE-ZIP?

Comment: when you make a WFS request you set the format (usually to gml) - if instead you set it to shape-zip you will get a zipped shapefile back

Answer (score 1):

To get features from a WFS to display on a map (as an OpenLayers layer) you would make a WFS GetFeature request and specify the output format as GML or JSON, something like:

For GML (default output)

```
http://ogc.bgs.ac.uk/digmap625k_gsml_insp_gs/ows?
SERVICE=WFS&
VERSION=1.0.0&
REQUEST=GetFeature&
TYPENAME=gsmlp:GBR_BGS_625k_BA_INSP&
SRSNAME=EPSG:27700&
```

The `outputFormat`parameter can be omitted

For JSON

```
http://ogc.bgs.ac.uk/digmap625k_gsml_insp_gs/ows?
SERVICE=WFS&
VERSION=1.0.0&
REQUEST=GetFeature&
TYPENAME=gsmlp:GBR_BGS_625k_BA_INSP&
SRSNAME=EPSG:27700&
outputFormat=application/json&
```

To get a zipped shapefile from a GeoServer WFS you need to change the outputFormat parameter on the request to `SHAPE-ZIP`, like:

```
http://ogc.bgs.ac.uk/digmap625k_gsml_insp_gs/ows?
SERVICE=WFS&
VERSION=1.0.0&
REQUEST=GetFeature&
TYPENAME=gsmlp:GBR_BGS_625k_BA_INSP&
SRSNAME=EPSG:27700&
outputFormat=SHAPE-ZIP&
```

You can find out what output formats are available for any service by looking at the GetCapabilities response, for example the above service gives the following output formats for the GetFeature operation:

```
<ows:Parameter name="outputFormat">
    <ows:AllowedValues>
        <ows:Value>text/xml; subtype=gml/3.2</ows:Value>
        <ows:Value>GML2</ows:Value>
        <ows:Value>KML</ows:Value>
        <ows:Value>SHAPE-ZIP</ows:Value>
        <ows:Value>application/gml+xml; version=3.2</ows:Value>
        <ows:Value>application/json</ows:Value>
        <ows:Value>application/vnd.google-earth.kml xml</ows:Value>
        <ows:Value>application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml</ows:Value>
        <ows:Value>csv</ows:Value>
        <ows:Value>gml3</ows:Value>
        <ows:Value>gml32</ows:Value>
        <ows:Value>json</ows:Value>
        <ows:Value>text/xml; subtype=gml/2.1.2</ows:Value>
        <ows:Value>text/xml; subtype=gml/3.1.1</ows:Value>
    </ows:AllowedValues>
```